# How to access and alter dynamically created multiple html form elements?

Tags: php, jquery, html, user-interface

I have a form with many input fields. I can't access and make changes on dynamically duplicated forms. I will show you just a portion of the fom to explain my problem.

```
<div>
  <input class="add check" type="checkbox" name="add"> <label for="check">Add</label>
</div>

<select disabled="true" class="classname">
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
</select>

<input name="percentage" type="text" class="percent medium" disabled="true" />                                        
<input name="amount" type="text" class="amount medium"  disabled="true" />
<div class="total medium process_price"></div>
```

This is the part of the form. When ADD checkbox is checked drop down is activated and when an option is selected, option value is retrieved from database and displayed on Total div. Now, I can manipulate Total by entering either amount or percentage field. I am able to duplicate this form with jQuery but I would like the duplicated form independently work from the original. How do I do that? This is what I have so far but the duplicated form is not working independently. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
$(".add").live('click',function(e){
    orginize($(e.target));
});

orginize(obj){
 var addCheck = obj.closest('div').find('input:checkbox');
 if(addCheck.is(':checked')){
   // Do stuff
 }
}
```

Comment: `.live()`? What version of jQuery are you using.

Comment: 1.8.3 I know it's old. There is no problem with the live() method though.

Comment: Yes there is. http://api.jquery.com/live/ "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated..." It's deprecated because it's very slow. Use `.on()`, and no `.on()` is not an alias, the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: your question is vague. 1) where is your code for the duplication of the form? 2) what do you intend to do with this duplicate? 3) where is the exact problem in your code? The code given should work fine in jQuery version before 1.9.

Comment: Appreciate your concern, but that not the problem now.

Comment: @darshanags This is how I duplicate. I wrapped the form around #machine-stattions `$(".machine-stations:first").clone().insertAfter(".machine-stations:last");` The problem is that when I click on ADD on the duplicated form it also affects the original form

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete relevant HTML and jQuery please? @u54r